# Removing the hash from the url in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I'm building a web app with Angular 1.x(not using ionic, building a website). I would like to remove the '#' from the URLs. I did implement html5mode true and put a base tag in the head tag in index.html. It works fine until I refresh the pages. When it is in html5mode it thinks that the URL is a request to the server. I'm developing in the local environment with gruntjs using the grunt-contrib-connect plugin and hosting my website in GoDaddy hosting in Linux Hosting Server. I would like to configure the html5mode(removing the hash from the URLs) in both environments(development and production). Note: I'm using ui.router with states if it matters in this problem.

Comment: HTML5 mode requires URL rewriting. For information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using $location (HTML5 Mode Server Side)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side).

Answer (score 0):

By default, `AngularJS` will route URLs with a hash(#).

**For example:**

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/#/about
http://example.com/#/contact
```

To remove the hashtag from the URL, you need to do two things

- Configuring `$locationProvider`
- Setting our base for relative links

  ---

**$location Service**

In **AngularJS**, the `$location` service parses the URL in the address bar and makes changes to application and vice versa.

**$locationProvider and html5Mode**

We will use the `$locationProvider` module and set `html5Mode` to true.

We will do this when defining Angular application and configuring routes.

```
angular.module('stackoverflow', [])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : homeController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : aboutController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : partialController
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

---

**Setting Relative Links**

To link around application using relative links, we will need to set a `<base>` in the `<head>` of your document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

There are many other ways to configure this and the `HTML5` mode set to true should automatically resolve relative links.